# Do (if yes, then why) some SATA to USB adapters have maximum supported drive size (except for 2^32 sectors limitation = 2TiB for 512b sector size)?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage

During web search I've found some SATA to USB adapters have limit of 2 TiB for 512 bytes sectors due to 32 bits limit on sector count.

Still I recall many other max sizes quoted, e.g. in that unanswered question: [Why do some SATA to USB adapters list a maximum supported drive size?](https://superuser.com/questions/1631164/why-do-some-sata-to-usb-adapters-list-a-maximum-supported-drive-size), where @Ramhound claims in comment section "The limitation comes from the SATA controller used in those products." w/out providing details.

Are there any more limits (except 32 bits for sector count and petabytes limits) due to hardware of an adapter? What are the technical reasons for them? TIA

Comment: Other than the 32 bit limitation 5, 12, 24 TB should work theoretically. Perhaps a manufacturer feels uncomfortable recommending any larger than tested. And perhaps manufacturer doesn't know what he's talking about because he's not really the manufacturer but simply brands a product that he gets from some Chinese factory. Perhaps he even limits the max capacity at firmware level, who knows ..

Comment: So I wonder if there are some adapters that works that way (limit at firmware level), if anybody had them; if they limit on sector count or TiB (by inserting both 512e and 4Kn drives).

Comment: Now you assume this is the case while I was just guessing, *'who knows?'*, that IF you indeed would find such an illogical limitation (5TB for example) it's  as if it's an artificial one ..

Comment: @JoepvanSteen,  I don't get how "So I wonder if there are " is same as "I assume there are". BTW, have you subscribed to the question (cause it is of interest what others will write)? Cause I had not added you username in comment before; IMO that my comment was not worth your attention, just a relevant thought.

Comment: I suggest, hypothesize, that at firmware level you can set any boundary you like, and so IF some odd, illogical boundary exists, it may be this is the case. That's all. You recall odd max sizes quoted in question and ask if there's logical explanations. I say, no, there are no logical explanations for max 4TB, 10TB as suggested in question you link to other than artificial ones.